# How do I avoid blocked kicks?

Tags: madden-17

Note: Everything in this question is about playing against the computer.

I've been playing Madden regularly for more than a decade. In every previous edition, blocked kicks were so rare as to be essentially impossible. I don't think I had *ever* had a PAT attempt blocked in all that time.

Now, my kicks get blocked quite regularly. Most of the time the computer just calls the Safe Man play when defending my kicks, which you can identify based on the way the edge rushers just play contain, rather than actually rushing the kicker. But, almost every single time they actually even *attempt* to block it, they succeed.

In real life, a good way to avoid having a kick blocked is to kick it at a high angle. In this game, I will put the kick at the highest possible angle, and still get it blocked every time.

Is there some way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've played additional decades of franchise after posting this question, with various different franchises.

It seems I was having some bad luck with those first couple. I was mostly playing divisional games, so I was mostly seeing the same opponents, and those opponents happened to have awesome kick blockers coming off the edges.

It also seems like the specific kicker might be a factor, as I've gone from having no kicks blocked to suddenly having one or two a game after signing a new rookie kicker. Perhaps their kicking animations are different speeds, or perhaps the kick power impacts the speed at which the ball leaves the hold, or perhaps it was just a coincidence and my opponents also got new blockers at that same time.

It seems like kicking the ball high does help a little, as I've had a defender who looked like they were going to block the kick whiff went it went over them.

Other than that, I don't think there's much you can do. Getting a better pass blocker to seal the edges on kicks might help, but I haven't specifically tested it. The edge blockers are backup tight ends and fullbacks.